# Kernel to Orthogonal Matrix relationship

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, orthogonality

Let $B$ be a matrix. How can I tell which ($\mathrm{img}(B)$, $\mathrm{ker}(B^T)$, $\mathrm{img}(B^T)$) spaces are necessarily orthogonal to $\mathrm{ker}(B)$ under standard dot product?

What are the implications of orthogonality from dot product?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by the second part of your question, *"what are the implications of orthogonality from dot product?"*

Comment: @Omnomnomnom how do we derive orthogonality from dot product procedures? Sorry for the lack of clarity.

Comment: Are $A$ and $B$ supposed to be different matrices? Or, are you asking why $\ker(A)$ is orthogonal to $\operatorname{image}(A^T)$?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom sorry I edited as suggested