# Orthogonality and Kernel Relationship Determination

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, orthogonality

Let B be a matrix. How can I tell which (img(B), ker(B^T), img(B^T)) spaces are necessarily orthogonal to ker(B) under **standard dot product**?

I know the image represents the column space, but I don't understand how we can relate that to determining orthogonality to the Kernel. What characteristic of a matrix shows orthogonality to the kernel?

Comment: How is this substantially different from [your previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2871079/265466)?

Comment: no one responded. So I have to ask the question again before it gets buried